# Kafka Consumer does not receive data when one of the brokers is down

Tags: apache-kafka

[Kafka Quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)
Using Kafka v2.1.0 on RHEL v6.9

Consumer fails to receive data when one of the Kafka brokers is down.

Steps performed:
    1. Start zookeeper
    2. Start Kafka-Server0 (localhost:9092, kafkalogs1)
    3. Start Kafka-Server1 (localhost:9094, kafkalog2)
    4. Create topic "test1", num of partitions = 1, replication factor = 2
    5. Run producer for topic "test1"
    6. Run consumer
    7. Send messages from the producer
    8. Receive messages on the consumer side.

All the above steps worked without any issues.

When I shutdown Kafka-Server0, the consumer stops getting data from Producer.
When I bring back up Kafka-Server0, the consumer starts to get messages from where it left off.

These are the commands used

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test1
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test1
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --topic test1
```

The behavior is the same (no message received on the consumer side) when I run the consumer with two servers specified in the --bootstrap-server option.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9094 --topic test1
```

Any idea why the consumer stops getting messages when server0 is down even though the replication factor for the topic test1 was set to 2?

There is a similar question already but it was not answered completely
[Kafka 0.10 quickstart: consumer fails when "primary" broker is brought down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756435/kafka-0-10-quickstart-consumer-fails-when-primary-broker-is-brought-down/53769906#53769906)

Comment: What is the replication factor of the consumer offsets topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the offsets topic is unavailable, you cannot consume.

Look at the `server.properties` file for these, and see the comment above, and increase accordingly (only applies if topic doesn't already exist)

```
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
```

According to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753415/what-is-this-topic-consumer-offsets-in-kafka), looks like it only has one replica

See how you can [increase replication factor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43518389/2308683) for an existing topic

Comment: Manually increasing the replication factor fixed the issue, thank you!. The manual process is a little bit cumbersome especially when you want to create JSON entries for the 50 partitions. I wonder if there is an easy way to do that.

Comment: u r correct @OneCricketeer, even though i changed property offsets.topic.replication.factor and restarted zookeeper/kafka several times but it didn't worked... FINALLY I described the topic "__consumer_offsets" and replication factor was 1 only.. Night Saver buddy --else I would have looked complete night for where I was going wrong.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Could you please guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67763076/connection-to-node-1-127-0-0-19092-could-not-be-established-broker-may-not

Answer (score 5):

In initial versions of Kafka, offset was being managed at zookeeper, but Kafka has continuously evolved over the time introducing lot of new features. Now Kafka manages the offset in a topic __consumer_offsets.

You can think of a scenario where you created a topic with a replication factor of 1. In case the broker goes down the data is only on that Kafka node which is down. So you can't get this data. Same analogy applies to __consumer_offsets topic.

You need to revisit the server.properties in order to get features you are expecting. But in case you still wanna consume the messages from the replica partition, you may need to re-start the console consumer with --from-beginning true

Comment: Thank you for the logical explanation. The server.properties did not help because the __consumer_offsets topic has already been created by Kafka automatically. The only way to fix this is to manually increase the replication factor for  __consumer_offsets as @cricket mentioned below.

Comment: Agreed, you have to increase it manually as topic has already been created. Keep up the good work!!