# Connection to node -1 (x.x.x.x/:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

my problem is i have setup 2 kafka brokers and 2 zookeeper nodes on different docker containers(Ubuntu).

Here is my configuration file of server1.properties

```
broker.id=1

############################# Socket Server Settings 

listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ipaddress_server1:9092
```

zookeeper.properties configuration file -

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=200
tickTime=2000
initLimit=20
syncLimit=10
```

this is are the properties for both the kafka and zookeeper servers. I have given unique broker id for each server and also create myid file insite /tmp/zookeeper dir.

now when i am testing kafka cluster by producing messages through only one ip address like this ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list  172.171.0.3:9092 --topic demo it works fine. But when i shutdown one container which is leader, still i am getting messages from the topic. But when i am running the consumer script again it is showing me WARN msgs : -

> Connection to node -1 (/172.171.0.3:9092) could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available

Now i am not able to get the messages, what should i do ???

Comment: Can you include the console-consumer command too?

Comment: Why are you manually using property files for containers? The Confluent, Bitnami, wurstmeister Kafka images all are completely configured through environment variables... But it any case, please show that Kafka is indeed starting rather than show the error of the clients

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Consumer does not receive data when one of the brokers is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771673/kafka-consumer-does-not-receive-data-when-one-of-the-brokers-is-down)

Comment: Hey mickael, here is the console consumer command. ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh — bootstrap-server 172.171.0.3:9092 —topic demo —from-beginning —partition 0

Comment: What is the replication factor of the consumer offsets topic? Value of property offsets.topic.replication.factor=1 in server.properties file

Comment: Hey Sammy i have entered value 2 foe offsets.topic.replication.factor